# Can't use concat function in Postgres (9.3) index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, concatenation

I'm creating an index over several text columns (in Postgres 9.3) and I would like to use `concat`, e.g:

```
CREATE INDEX 
ON my_table
USING gin (to_tsvector('english', concat(title, ' ', description)))
```

However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

`ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Vanilla concatenation with the `||` operator works fine. However, I'd prefer to use `concat` since `description` might be `NULL`, and the `||` operator seems to turn any concatenation with `NULL` into `NULL`.

If I understand this correctly this means that `concat` is not marked as immutable, which I don't understand.

Of course, I can just `coalesce` all the nullable columns, but it feels inelegant. More than anything, I'm curious as to why I can't use `concat` in my index?

Comment: Take a look at `concat_ws()` which handles the NULL cases, too.

Comment: The [recommended method (from the docs)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-DOCUMENTS) is to use `coalesce()` inside `to_tsvector()` (and the `tsvector` concatenation with `||`), f.ex.: `to_tsvector('english',coalesce(title,'')) || to_tsvector('english',coalesce(description,''))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason `CONCAT` is not `IMMUTABLE` was explained by Tom Lane in [this post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3361.1410026366@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> concat() invokes datatype output functions, which are not necessarily
>   immutable.  An easy example is that timestamptz_out's results depend
>   on the TimeZone setting.

I.e. that's due to the fact that it will accept non-text input, which may change based on session settings when converted to text.

You'll probably have to roll your own function for this.