# Indexing LIKE query on full name

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database I often use the following query:

```
SELECT "consultant_profiles".* 
FROM "consultant_profiles" 
WHERE (LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name)) LIKE LOWER('john%'))
```

I want to have an index on that so my database will not need to do a sequential scan every time.
I tried something like this but database is not using this index:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_consultant_profile_name 
  ON consultant_profiles USING btree (lower(first_name), lower(last_name) text_pattern_ops)
```

Comment: Your index and your query have to use **identical** expressions. Your query uses a single expression with `concat_ws()` but your index contains _two_ expressions that are not concatenated

Comment: When I do it this way: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_consultant_profile_name ON consultant_profiles USING btree (LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name)) text_pattern_ops)

then I get the following error: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat_ws()` is probably marked as not immutable for the same reason why [concat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608699) isn't.

You can use the `||` operator instead, which will require fiddling with coalesce() to properly deal with `null` values. You will have to use the exact same expression in your query.

Alternatively you can create an immutable function with the necessary expression because you know that in this case the `concat_ws()` function is indeed immutable. You then have to use that function in your query.

```
create function search_name(p_first_name text, p_last_name text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', p_first_name, p_last_name));
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then create the index using that function:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_consultant_profile_name 
  ON consultant_profiles (search_name(first_name,last_name) text_pattern_ops);
```

and change your query to:

```
SELECT consultant_profiles.* 
FROM consultant_profiles 
WHERE search_name(first_name, last_name) LIKE LOWER('john%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

according to this answer [IMMUTABLE in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5974303/5193370) you must create a new function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOWER_CONCAT_I(text1 text, text2 text) 
  RETURNS text
AS
$BODY$
    select LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', text1, text2));
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

and use it in your query:

```
SELECT "consultant_profiles".* 
FROM "consultant_profiles" 
WHERE LOWER_CONCAT_I(first_name, last_name) LIKE LOWER('john%')
```

and create the corresponding index:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_consultant_profile_name 
  ON consultant_profiles USING btree (LOWER_CONCAT_I(first_name, last_name) text_pattern_ops)
```